# Best way to save waypoints before storing in database?

Tags: html, database, list

I am trying to create a website, where I can create some waypoints on a map. Every waypoint should have some data stored in it, ex. name, coordinates, description etc..

At the moment I know how to create the waypoints and show them in a list in HTML, where I can drag and change the order they should be in. I also know how I can delete a checkpoint.

My problem is that I don't know how I can store the data in each list item, so that this data will be deleted as well when the item is deleted. I am thinking about storing it in a `JSON`-object on the client, so it only will be stored in the database when editing is finished?

Is it possible? - If it is, what should I use to accomplish it? You don't have to show me how, just what I need. At the moment I am primarily using javascript, but I am open to everything that can help me(besides MS dependent software or Apple dependent software).